# Python regular expression not extracting value - Python 3.x

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, nltk

I am looping through a very large (~5GB) text document like so:

```
<P ID=912>
bird
dog
dog
dog
</P>

<P ID=5>
aardvark
bird
bird
cat
egret
</P>

<P ID=291>
aardvark
aardvark
aardvark
aardvark
aardvark
bird
dog
fish
fish
fish
</P>

<P ID=621>
aardvark
aardvark
bird
dog
fish
fish
fish
</P>

<P ID=5>
bird
egret
egret
</P>

<P ID=1>
bird
</P>
```

The document is very much so "out of order" in the sense that the IDs are not organized. I need to create a solution that loops through each paragraph (denoted by the `<P ID = x></P>` tags, which will always be there), and extract the ID number.

I am using `NLTK` to tokenize the paragraphs which works great, my issue is I cannot extract the `ID` from the tag.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, RegexpTokenizer
import re

def get_input(filepath):
    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    content = f.read()
    return content

def main():
    myfile = get_input("filepath")
    p = r'<P ID=\d+>(.*?)</P>'    
    paras = RegexpTokenizer(p)
    para_id = 0

    for para in paras.tokenize(myfile):
        para_id = re.match("<P ID=\d+>", para)        
        print("Current paragraph Number: {}".format(para_id))

main()
```

Is resulting in:

```
Current paragraph Number: None
Current paragraph Number: None
Current paragraph Number: None
Current paragraph Number: None
Current paragraph Number: None
Current paragraph Number: None
```

However I would expect it to look like:

```
Current paragraph Number: 912
Current paragraph Number: 5
Current paragraph Number: 291
Current paragraph Number: 621
Current paragraph Number: 5
Current paragraph Number: 1
```

How do I need to change: `para_id = re.match("<P ID=\d+>", para)`

**Edit:**
I have also tried:
`para_id = [i['id'] for i in soup(para, 'html.parser').find_all('p')]`
but that yields a blank `[]` I am not sure why I cannot create a soup of just the singular paragraph

N.B. - I should mention this is a minimal example of the code. Real program is much larger, and requires NLTK to parse through because I am doing a lot with stop words and text tokenizing.

Comment: You probably just need `re.search` instead of `re.match`.

Comment: Unfortunately changing `re.match` to `re.search` yields the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where capturing the Text of the paragraph but 
you should capture the full paragraph including P tags,
after that you capture the Id of paragraph, I used your simple in `data.txt`:

```py
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, RegexpTokenizer
import re

def get_input(filepath):
    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    content = f.read()
    f.close()  # don't forget to close file
    return content

def main():
    myfile = get_input("data.txt")
    # here capture the full paragraph
    p = r'<P ID=\d+>.*?</P>'
    paras = RegexpTokenizer(p)
    para_id = 0
    for para in paras.tokenize(myfile):
        # and here just catch the ID
        para_id = re.match("<P ID=(\d+)>", para)
        print("Current paragraph Number: {}".format(para_id.group(1)))

main()
```

OUPUT:

```
Current paragraph Number: 912
Current paragraph Number: 5
Current paragraph Number: 291
Current paragraph Number: 621
Current paragraph Number: 5
Current paragraph Number: 1
```

You are reading the entire 5 GB file I think you should use generator for this,
If you just need to print paragraph Id:

```
import re


def main():
    with open("data.txt") as f:  # Using context manager to close resource
        for line in f:
            # and here just catch the ID
            match = re.match("<P ID=(\d+)>", line)
            if match:
                print("Current paragraph Number: {}".format(match.group(1)))

main()
```

This will generate the same result without loading the entire 5 GB to memory.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to pass your input, after processing using `NLTK`, to `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
results = [i['id'] for i in soup(content, 'html.parser').find_all('p')]
```

Output:

```
['912', '5', '291', '621', '5', '1']
```

`BeautifulSoup` gives you the ability to access the paragraph content using `soup.contents`:

```
for i in soup(content, 'html.parser').find_all('p'):
   print(i.contents)
```

Output:

```
['\nbird\ndog\ndog\ndog\n']
['\naardvark\nbird\nbird\ncat\negret\n']
['\naardvark\naardvark\naardvark\naardvark\naardvark\nbird\ndog\nfish\nfish\nfish\n']
['\naardvark\naardvark\nbird\ndog\nfish\nfish\nfish\n']
['\nbird\negret\negret\n']
['\nbird\n']
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have never used `BeautifulSoup`, so this is good to know about. How can I use this in my paragraph looping as I mentioned (the real program requires looping through the paragraphs to do some text parsing and other things)

Comment: @JerryM. Please see my recent edit. `BeautifulSoup` enables you to utilize the `soup.contents` attribute to access all the child values under a tag.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and see if I can get this to work in my for loop format I have posted and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `r'(?s)<P\s*ID\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*>(.*?)</P\s*>'` with a findall() search.
The `ID` is in capture group 1 and the `Content` is in capture group 2.

Example

```
>>> input = """
... <P ID=912>
... bird
... dog
... dog
... dog
... </P>
...
... <P ID=5>
... aardvark
... bird
... bird
... cat
... egret
... </P>
...
... <P ID=291>
... aardvark
... aardvark
... aardvark
... aardvark
... aardvark
... bird
... dog
... fish
... fish
... fish
... </P>
...
... <P ID=621>
... aardvark
... aardvark
... bird
... dog
... fish
... fish
... fish
... </P>
...
... <P ID=5>
... bird
... egret
... egret
... </P>
...
... <P ID=1>
... bird
... </P>
... """
>>>
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r'(?s)<P\s*ID\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*>(.*?)</P\s*>')
>>>
>>> ids = p.findall(input)
>>>
>>> i = 0
>>> ids_len = len(ids)
>>>
>>> while ( i < ids_len ):
...     print(ids[i])     # The ID
...     print(ids[i+1])   # The Content
...     i += 2
...
('912', '\nbird\ndog\ndog\ndog\n')
('5', '\naardvark\nbird\nbird\ncat\negret\n')
('291', '\naardvark\naardvark\naardvark\naardvark\naardvark\nbird\ndog\nfish\nfish\nfish\n')
('621', '\naardvark\naardvark\nbird\ndog\nfish\nfish\nfish\n')
('5', '\nbird\negret\negret\n')
('1', '\nbird\n')
>>>
```

Comment: Can you please post the example?